# Get range of Dataframe Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So I've loaded a dataframe from a parquet file. This dataframe now contains an unspecified number of columns. The first column is a Label, and the following are features.

I want to save each row in the dataframe as a LabeledPoint.

So far im thinking:

```
val labeledPoints: RDD[LabeledPoint] =df.map{row => LabeledPoint(row.getInt(0),Vectors.dense(row.getDouble(1),row.getDouble(2)))}
```

Its easy to get the column indexes, but when handling a lot of columns this won't hold. I'd like to be able to load the entire row starting from index 1 (since index 0 is the label) into a dense vector.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```scala
df.map {
  row: Row => 
    val data = for (index <- 1 until row.length) yield row.getDouble(index)
    val vector = new DenseVector(data.toArray)
    new LabeledPoint(row.getInt(0), vector)
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, i just had to edit "val vector = new DenseVector(data.toArray)" to : " val vector=Vectors.dense(data.toArray)" Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear that it solved your problem :-) Btw: What did you have to change to make it work?

Comment: Nothing really, now that i think about it. I just hadn't imported DenseVector xS. So i used Vectors.dense instead of new DenseVector. Thanks again